# Testing IBM LTO 7 hh drive out of its library tray

Tags: ibm, lto, library, test

I am trying to diagnose a library drive for wich I don´t have a library. It belongs to a ibm 4300 library.
I connected an atx psu to the mini molex 4 pin connector on the drive, and as soon as I turn the psu on, the drive just blinks the front lights once and shuts off.
Is the drive expecting something from the library or from the pcb on the tray, or it should turn on just fine and something is wrong with my psu?

Comment: It probably has a SAS interface. You should attach that as well.

Comment: imho, RTM, about the drive, usually it's described, and if it's still having warranty why do you care? open up a ticket on the vendor support and if not get a new one with warranty

Comment: Its a fc interface, will atach it to see what happens. I do not think the data cable has anything to do, as the many other lto 6 drives I have power up just fine when no data interface is connected. (they may not come online if they don´t see a library, but they initialize just fine). Regarding warranty, no, I bought this unit second hand with no warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to run any decent test of the drive, you will need to connect the interface and insert a tape. A cleaning tape won't do! Get an LTO tape!

Most removable media devices don't do squat until you put media in it. Tape drives are no different. They barely talk to you or do a dang thing without tape inserted.

If you go through and configure your tapes.conf file with the media length, heads and all ... you can read/write data to the tape drive. It can be oddly fascinating to manipulate external devices with the command-line. Or create a thingie that has buttons? Robots in libraries can be hella fun, too!

I don't think I've ever seen a removable media test rig that doesn't include an entire computer? I've had drive workstations for hdd repair and data recovery. Check your drive I suppose? If you find it non-functional, you may find it's still under warranty? They may replace it with a NIB replacement?
Happy day!!!

Comment: It finally booted up fine using a different psu. It seems the other one was weak. LTO drives do talk to the host even when no media is inserted. But most library drives will not come online unless they see a library connected to their serial port. Now the drive initializes fine but it does not come online, will have to get a library to test it. As for writting to tape, I am using ltfs wich lets you format and use the tapes as a regular hard drive (exept of course they are linear!).